# I am refactoring payments module for my site. It has got many providers, modes and operation and they keep on adding. Need advice on its architecture

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, refactoring

The payments module currently written uses if-else blocks to perform operations for different payments providers, payment modes, and operations. When there is a requirement to add another of these providers or modes or operation, people were just copying and pasting another else-if.

I am refactoring it by using commands for each operation for each provider. Say, a command for 'credit card authentication by some provider A' and a command for 'net banking sales by provider B' and so on.

But *the problem is* commands don't return values but i have made them do it. Now there is no strict type checking on the return types. In the service i am invoking commands from i have to do explicit typecasting, something like this:

```
PaymentCommand command = commandsManager.getFactory(emiScheme.getPaymentProvider().getCode())
                .create(PaymentActionEnum.EMI_SCHEME_VALIDATION.name());

        return (EmiSchemeValidationResult) command.execute(schemeValidationRequest);
```

Is it a legit side-effect of using commands here? Or should I use commands in some other way to return results? Or should i use something else to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solutions seems good to me. I use similar techniques and they work well.

Having **Commands** encapsulate some application logic is a good pattern and returning results from them is not a bad thing. If you don't do it this way that means that you will have to make additional queries to figure out the result and this could lead to bad performance. Why is it bad to return a result from a **Command** to avoid having one or more calls to a database?

If you are referring to principles like [CQS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) that say that **Commands** should not return results, we may have to talk a bit more about the definition of a **Command**. This principle is for objects in a OO system and applies to methods on objects, not for **Commands** as object that do some application logic as Martin Fowler explains [here](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html), You can apply it wherever you like of couse. No one stops you, but in order to fully understand something you need to now it was conceived.

It's better to think of these **command** methods as **state mutators** of an object. If they server both as mutators and queries things can be harder to understand and use. Sometimes however it's useful to have a **command/mutator** method that changes the state and return a result. as in the case of a **Stack.Pop()**. It's better to stick to this pattern most of the time, but if you can't just don't.

Defining a common interface that should returning a result that can vary in a strongly typed language can be challenging. If you do it in a language like JavaScript then it's not a problem. You either return a result or not. If you do, then the receiver will check what properties this object has. In my experience with both loose typed and strong typed languages this is one of the things that is easier to implement. Because you have a dynamic data returned from the same method.

Here are couple of different ways you can do it:

- The one you use: Use different types for each result and cast to it.
- Don't define a common interface for all commands like **ICommand**. Define common interface for a family of commands. Make your factory return the most common class like object that you will cast later to **IPaymentCommand**. This will be an interface for all **PaymentCommands**. **IPaymentCommand.Execute** will return **EmiSchemeValidationResult** and your fine. I have used this and works well if you know in advance the type that you going to receive. If you execution code needs to be more general this can cause problems
- Define a result class that contains a key/value pair with the results (store them in HashMap in Java, Dictionary in C# something like that). Your simulating the JavaScript example with this. Good pattern but it will make the command result processing code code more cumbersome to write. Sometimes it can even get nasty and piss you off every time you need to write it.
- Add a property with the result to the **Command**. If you already have the type of the command like **PaymentCommand**. Add **EmiSchemeValidationResult PaymentCommand.Result** property to it and check this after the command executes. I have used this pattern too and it has worked well.

It depends on the needs of your code and what you (and/or your team) are comfortable with.

Here is an article that explains these things in more detail:
https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandOrientedInterface.html

Comment: I was just worried about the as many explicit casts as there are types of commands. I think that is the only side effect. Otherwise, as you mentioned,  i have created sub interfaces to type check a class of commands and there request/response objects.

Comment: I'm facing the same issues too when working with strong typed languages in these situations. Unfortunately sometimes you just have to do casting. These issues occur when working with a lot of dynamic data. I have a situation where events are stored in an event log. These events are then deserialized to a .NET class instance that implements a base interface IEvent. After that when I need to process a specific event I need to do casting to the concrete .NET class. Sucks.. but the other solution is to use dynamic keyword (available in .NET) and there is no type checking to help, so I do casting.